# How to replace one ore more empty space or white spaces in a string of 6 number by zeros?

Tags: r, regex, replace, whitespace, detection

I have the following dataframe

```
dput(head(phone_numbers_df)) 

structure(list(phone_number = c("30 969166", "31    8941", "32   34057",  "33   24021", "34 685284", "36 226317"), prefix = c("30", "31",  "32", "33", "34", "36")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

there should always be 6 numbers in the suffix of phone_number. some have 5 or 4 since generated from random numbers. How to replace the white spaces by zeros?

I have tried the following but the regex used does not seem to detect the white spaces properly

```
 library(tidyverse)

fixed_numbers <- phone_numbers_df %>%
  mutate(needs_replacement = str_detect(needs_replacement , "\\s{1,6}$")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(needs_replacement), ~ ifelse(. == TRUE, str_replace(., "\\s{1,6}$", "000000"), .))

# Display the fixed phone numbers
print(fixed_numbers)
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you want something like `df$phone_number <- gsub("\\s(?=.{0,5}$)", "0", df$phone_number, perl=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to first detect and then replace. According to your description and code, you want to replace each ' ' with "0" only in the last 6 characters.

```
phone_numbers_df %>%
  mutate(needs_replacement = paste(prefix, str_replace_all(str_sub(phone_number, -6), '\\s', '0'), sep = ' ')) 
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  phone_number prefix needs_replacement
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr>            
1 30 969166    30     30 969166        
2 31    8941   31     31 008941        
3 32   34057   32     32 034057        
4 33   24021   33     33 024021        
5 34 685284    34     34 685284        
6 36 226317    36     36 226317
```

Perhaps this looks better. Leaving random white spaces between prefix and number does not make sense to me. You can even get rid of the white spaces at all if you wish.

Comment: I *think* what the OP is looking for is the last set of digits to be length six, left padded with zero. For example, nothing would be done to `30 969166` since `969166` is already six digits. `31    8941` would be `31 008941` since `8941` is only four digits and should be six.

Comment: @LMc Oh, I see.  It is very counterintuitive to keep white spaces anywhere in the phone number.

Comment: Yes, @Jinjin codes work for me! however, it seems also to add an extra "digit" to the prefix where it was originally also white space  see